# How to remove surrounding quotes inside a String in Erlang?

Tags: string, erlang

I am using `epgsql` to query a database, in Erlang. It returns string results including quotation marks surrounding them like this: `"what_was_in_the_row"`.  How can I remove these quotation marks before working with the result?

Comment: Are you sure it has double quotes? How are you checking? `io:format("~p", ...)` will print an extra double quotes around the string.

Comment: @Dogbert I am putting it and another value in a string with io_lib:format("~p ~p", [Value1, Value2]), and sending it over a socket to a Python program.  The python program sees it as having quotes.  I am currently stripping the quotes away on the Python side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the control format `~p` (pretty print) keeps information about the type of the variables that are printed. You are printing a string, which is, in erlang, a standard integer list made of printable characters for example `[101,102,103]` is displayed as `"efg"` in the shell.

If you call `io_lib:format("~p",[[101,102,103]]).`, you will get the result `["\"efg\""]` which needs some explanation.

- The surrounding brackets indicate a list, which is the return value type of `io_lib:format/2`,
- then the first double quotes indicates another list that maybe a string, it is syntactic sugar, but it is not part of the result (I say maybe because any list that looks like a string will be displayed as a string with pretty print),
- finally the `\"` is an escape sequence that represents the single character "

You can evaluate the length of each string to verify the difference:

- 3 = length("efg").
- 5 = length("\"efg\"").

If you want to get the string without the surrounding quotes, you must use the control format `~s`

```
1> [Res] = io_lib:format("~s",[[101,102,103]]).
["efg"]
2> length(Res).
3
3> [Res] = io_lib:format("~s",[Res]).          
["efg"]
```

Of course, the last line shows that my example is stupid. With `io_lib:format("~s ~s!",["Hello","world"]).` or any more complex formatting, the result is of type `chars()`: a  list of `char()` or `chars()`.